# I need a formula for excel to divide column a by column b if column c="Completed"

Tags: excel, formula

I need a formula for excel to divide column a by column b if column `c="Completed"`. I've tried `=IF(AK5="Completed",E13/AE13)`. Need a little help.

Comment: Your formula is correct as far as I can see.  The only ovious issue is that you lack an ELSE condition i.e. what do you want to see as the result if c <> "Completed"?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

`=IF(C2="Completed", A2/B2,"")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is:

```
=IF(EXACT(AK5, "COMPLETED"), E13/AE13)
```

Note that if C1 is not COMPLETED, the formula will return FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the third argument to Excel's if-statement. Try:

IF(C2 = "Completed", A2/B2, "")